# Stuck on search js

Tags: javascript, html, search

```
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    ul.style.display = "block";
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code I have for Search but it's not working the way I need it to.

Example:

The element I want to search for is "Water Purifier - New York".

I want it to filter it even when I type Water New in search, but it doesn't. Basically, search needs to look for all elements containing given words regardless of order of those words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example works fine, add an eventListener on input change and you should be able to filter out your records

Also adjusted the search criteria so that it renders elements based on the inserted letters.

For example:

1.)
input: wtr; output: Water Purifier - New York, world trade render

2.)
input: wtrp;
output: Water Purifier - New York

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = e.target.value.toUpperCase()
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  ul.style.display = "block";
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (filter.split('')
      .every(x => txtValue.toUpperCase().split('').some(y => y === x))) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  myFunction(e)
})
```

```html
<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Water Purifier - New York,</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Poland</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Something3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">world trade render</a></li>
</ul>

<input id="search" type="text" />
```

Comment: Sorry, I've been quite busy in the past few days. My code was working fine, it just didn't work as I intended. So far it's working like:

Input: wr

and the list has Water Purifier - New York, it should display it.

So, basically I need it to look for characters independently. Even if the characters are not in the exact order to match, it should still filter it (including space).

Example: 

input: wtr

<li>Water Purifier - New York</li>
.
.
.

Filter would not filter it out, only if the input is the exact match.

Comment: @Mezmerizer9 does it work ok or do you need another type of search?

Comment: Apparently I need some other type of search hah.

Comment: @Mezmerizer9 try now, if you type  'wtr' you ll get 2 records, if you type wtrp only 1 record and so on, so it matches all typed chars

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thank you very much.